# Need finer tuning on regular expression with html

Tags: regex, vba

What I want to do is to figure out how you use a regular expression to extract the inner most item from a HTML tag collection. That is:
TARGET TEXT

```
Function FindInnerHtml(Work As String) As String
Dim Results As String, myRegExp, myMatches As Object, thisMatch As Object
  Let myRegExp = New RegExp
  myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
  myRegExp.Global = True
  myRegExp.Pattern = ">(.*?)<"
  Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(Work)
  If (myMatches.Count = 0) Then
    Results = myMatches(0)
    Results = Replace$(Replace$(Results, ">", ""), "<", "")
  End If
  FindInnerHtml = Results
End Function
```

What I do get from the function is the inner HTML, that is the target text, what I would rather be able to do is to ensure I'm not in need of adding that double replace$() to clean up the results.

Comment: did you have an url in mind or some test html? Also, is this not possible with an html parser?

Comment: Sample: <td align="center" id="3_T_9" nowrap="">6:00:00 AM - 10:00:00 AM</td>

And you speak of this mystery element called "an html parser" which interests me greatly because I've been writing my own forever and ever, ...

Comment: can you use snippet tool via [edit] to show more of the table html? Preferably all if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's crude and fails miserably for edge cases but something like this could work:

```
<[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z\d]*>([^><]*)</[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z\d]*>
```

`$1` will contain the inner text

https://regex101.com/r/iuLdJV/3

Comment: I tried my sample from above in the page and it fails.